# How to modify actual data once only from a SQL Server Database Project?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013

I have a [SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio 2013](http://spr.com/leveraging-visual-studio-2013-sql-server-database-projects/) with a couple of;

- Tables
- Stored procedures
- Some PostDeployment scripts

I will leave the tables and stored procedures now, and focus on the PostDeployment scripts, as I feel those are the ones most interesting for my question.

Say for example I want to remove some data that was previously caused by a bug. Now the bug has been fixed but i'd like to set the database into a better state by removing the "wrong" information. What I need is script that is executed once-only ever. With a change-script approach this would be trivial, but I cannot find a solution for this type of database project.

PostDeployment scripts are executed after *each* deploy, meaning I cannot really do any meaningful *once-only* change to the actual data here.

I *could* include an `IF` statement in the scipt to check the data before making the change, preventing it from being executed multiple times, but I'd prefer to rely on the tools rather than a user-written `IF` statement.

I feel my use case is rather simple, yet I cannot find a solution for it. How shall I approach this? Thanks for all tips!

Comment: Can't you just do it manually in SSMS?

Comment: I could do that @Dan, but I prefer to have it under source control as well as not having manual steps in the deployment pipeline. I want it to be part of the normal deployment (publish) of the project.

Comment: Write an *idempotent* script - developers do this on a regular basis to manage exactly the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [Pieter Geerkens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1624450/pieter-geerkens):

> Write an idempotent script - developers do this on a regular basis to
>   manage exactly the problem you describe.

---

This seem to be the way to. The reason why I didn't want to take this approach at first is because it *will* execute the script during each publish. In some future if the data again satisfies the conditions data might again be updated / deleted / removed, and I'd prefer this not to happen.

For reference: [Idempotent](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/08/idempotent-db-update-scripts/)